# Java 1.4.2 - ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

(I am using Java 1.4.2) I wanted to have an array that should flip a 'coin' a certain amount of times given by the user (the coin can flip up to 1000 times). Then randomly generate an integer between 1 and ten, store all the numbers in an array. I have the following code but it keeps on giving me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
>   at CoinFlip.main(CoinFlip.java:42)

Here is the code I wrote.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class CoinFlip
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // setting up variables
        String timesString;
        int times;
        // setting up input
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        do
        {
            // times will display how many times the coin will flip
            // loop if times does not fulfill the requirements
            System.out.println("How many times do you want the coin to flip? (MUST be an integer between 1 to 1000)");
            timesString = in.readLine();
            // convert timesString into an integer
            times = Integer.valueOf(timesString).intValue();
            if((times > 1000)||(times < 1))
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: The number of times you flip the coin must be an integer between 1 and 1000.");
            }
            System.out.println("The value for times is " +times);
        }
        while((times > 1000)||(times < 1));


        // create a new array
        double flip[] = new double[times];

        // create a new variable timeStore that sets the boolean conditions for the For Loop
        int timeStore;
        for(timeStore = 0; timeStore <= times-1; timeStore++)
        {
            System.out.println("timeStore (how many iterations) is " +timeStore);
            System.out.println("FOR LOOP:  When " +timeStore+ " is less than or equal to " +(times-1));
            flip[times] = Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1;
            // the line above stores a random integer between 1 and 10 within the current index
            System.out.println("flip["+times+"] = "+flip[times]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Next time, please don't make us count (or intelligently try to discern) where line 42 is. Also, thanks for making it [line 42](http://bit.ly/kQG2PA). :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At line 42;

```
flip[times] = Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1;
```

Should be;

```
flip[timeStore] = Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1;
```

Then also in the System.out on line 44.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did what you suggested and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

These are wrong:

```
42: flip[times] = Math.round(Math. random()* 9 ) + 1;
44: System.out.println("flip[" + times + "] = " + flip[times]);
```

It appears you meant

```
42: flip[timeStore] = Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1;
44: System.out.println("flip["+timeStore+"] = "+flip[timeStore]);
```

Since you declared `flip` as an array of size `times`, only indices `0...(times - 1)` are valid. In particular, index `times` is invalid and so `flip[times]` will throw.

Note that the compiler was telling you the offending line, and the offending index passed in. It's telling you you passed in `7` as the index. But note, this exception is happening on the *first* iteration of your loop. You can tell this by the output that your program would have produced since you have helpful print debugging statements in your code. Thus, you should have been able to reason: hey, why is my array seeing the index 7 on the *first* iteration of the loop when the index should be 0? At that point, the error practically figures itself out.

Also, idiomatic usage of arrays is:

```
for(timeStore = 0; timeStore < times; timeStore++)
```

but *even* better is:

```
for(timeStore = 0; timeStore < flip.length; timeStore++)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also am new to Stack Overflow so I am not sure how to label the code with numbers on the side.

Comment: @danjonila: Well, you don't have to label *all* of the line numbers, just label the offending line numbers.

Comment: How exactly would I be able to do that?

Comment: @danjonila: Put a comment in the source in your answer that says `// error on this line`. Or, extract the offending line from your source and say "Here is the line that is referred to the error: `flip[times] = Math.round(Math. random()* 9 ) + 1;`. Here is the full source for context:" and then give the full source (like you already did). Double plus good would be to do both!

Comment: Thanks. I also have another question regarding reading files. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148203/java-1-4-2-reading-files/18148391