# Java 1.4.2 - Reading Files

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read a simple file and then a file which the user is supposed to select. I keep on getting the following error though:

> Readzilla.java:37: cannot find symbol
>
> symbol  : method FileReader(java.lang.String)
>
> location: class java.io.BufferedReader
>
> line = read.FileReader(newDoc);

Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;

    public class Readzilla
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            String line;
            BufferedReader read;
            // BufferedReader "read" reads the file
            BufferedReader in;
            // BufferedReader "in" reads the input sent by the user  
            String loop;
            // "loop" decides whether another document should be read

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("message.txt"));
            line = read.readLine();

            while(line != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = read.readLine();
            }

            // read another document
            System.out.println("Would you like to read another document? (Y/N)");
            loop = in.readLine();
            loop = loop.toUpperCase();

            if (loop == "Y")
            {
                do
                {
                    System.out.println("What file (.txt) would you like to read?");
                    String newDoc = in.readLine();
                    // newDoc reads a text file of the user's choosing
                    line = read.FileReader(newDoc);
                    //  ^ This line constantly gives errors
                    System.out.println("Reading...");
                    line = read.readLine();

                    while(line != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        line = read.readLine();
                    }

                    // read another document
                    System.out.println("Would you like to read another document? (Y/N)");
                    loop = in.readLine();
                }
                while (loop == "Y");    
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Closing Program...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to replace erroneus line with read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("newDoc"));

Comment: @ice: No quotes, `newDoc` is a `String`.

Comment: Maybe try to specify an encoding for the file instead of assuming the default encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
line = read.FileReader(newDoc);
```

There is no method named [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) on the class [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), which is how the compiler is interpreting that line. `FileReader` is itself a class, and it looks like you're trying to open a new file for reading. Thus, you'd want to say something like:

```
BufferedReader doc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newDoc));
```

After that, you'd want to replace

```
line = read.readLine();
```

with

```
line = doc.readLine()
```

because that's how you'd read from the document referenced by the `BufferedReader doc`.

Additionally, you have a problem here (twice that I see):

```
loop == "Y"
```

In Java, `==` is *reference* equality *only*. You absolutely want value equality here so say:

```
"Y".equals(loop);
```

This is a common mistake; `==` as reference equality only was a poor design decision IMO.

Comment: But didn't I already define a FileReader at: read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("message.txt")); ?

Comment: You need another one if you're opening another file. And either way `read.FileReader` is 100% invalid because there is *no* method on `BufferedReader` named `FileReader`.

Comment: So for each file I need a new FileReader? Isn't that a little too much? If I needed 100 FileReaders then I would need 100 'new' statements (or loop the same 'new' statement 100 times)?

Comment: @danjonila: Yes. Why do you expect that to not be the case? A `FileReader` is tied to a *particular* file.

Comment: Oh. So how would I make it read any file? (As you may have already guessed, I just started learning Java 1.4.2 on an online course. It doesn't do a very good job at teaching though.)

Comment: @danjonila: You can't make a `FileReader` read *any* file. You can only make it read a *particular* file, but that file can be arbitrary. Once you attached a file to a `FileReader`, that `FileReader` is forever bound to that file.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding now. Thank you so much for the help. I will contact you if I need any more help.

Comment: What does the '.equals' do and how do I use it in a general case?

Comment: Compares two objects for *value* equality. Every object has an `equals` method on it that you can invoke on it to compare to another object.

Comment: So what is reference equality VS. value equality?

Comment: Reference equality means exactly the same object in memory. Value equality means that they are equal from some logical perspective (e.g., `String s = new String("Hello, World!"); String t = new String("Hello, World!")` will create two strings that are *different* in memory, but equal from a *logical* perspective because they represent the same *text*. That is `s == t` is `false` but `s.equals(t)` is true.

Comment: I was always thought that strings were defined in the following manner: `String x = "I am new to programming"`. Is this wrong?

Comment: That's *a* way to define a `String`. Now we are getting into tricky things though. If I had instead said `String s = "Hello, World!"` and `String t = "Hello, World!"` then `s` and `t` would be equal as references and as values because of some magic that the compiler does called interning. See, `String`s are special, they are one of the few types that you can instantiate with a literal. But the compiler will take all `String`s assigned with the same literal and refer them to the same instance rather than separate instances.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot invoke a constructor from an object, only when you create the object with 'new'. You would just say 'line = read.readLine();' for the problem line.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` class doesn't have a method called `FileReader`.

You can see it in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

One way of reading a file in Java 1.4.2 is:

```
try
{
    String line;
    File file = new File(file);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while((line = inFile.readLine()) != null)
    {
            System.out.println(line)
    }
    inFile.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("problem with file");
}
```